# Shuffling - no duplicates JAVA

Tags: java, reference, duplicates, shuffle

I am trying to create a List of Integer arrays by taking one integer array and shuffling it a number of times. However, once I shuffle the array, the initial array is also modified since it works by reference! Is there any way I can add a variation of the initial array (which is already resident in the list) without creating a new array please?

Thanks!

Comment: No. You can't have two different arrays from a single one without creating a new one.

Comment: Copy the array, shuffle the copy.

Comment: but then if i need to create say 100 from the initial array, I have to create 100 copies..

Comment: Where are you going to store the shuffled array if you don't store it either in the original array, or a copy?

Comment: List<Integer> oldArray = new ArrayList<>();
oldArray.add(1);
List<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<>(oldArray);
now you play with newArray

Comment: Be happy, you not have to create say 100.000 copies from the initial array. That could last for a whole second!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the array using `System.arrayCopy` then use `Collections.shuffle` on the original.